# Is Fast Fourier transform algorithm appropriate for image gradient computation?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, fft

I've a matrix of size `mXn` and a filter `[-1 0 1]` on which I need to perform convolution. I'm able to do this in O(n^2) steps, but on further googling fast fourier transform keeps on popping up everywhere. I would like to know if FFT is appropriate for this problem. The matrix has random integers only. But if I were to have floating values, will it make a difference? Is FFT meant for a problem like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your filter has only two nonzero elements, computing the convolution by definition will only take `O(n*m)` steps (which is the size of your data). FFT isn't gonna help you in that case: a 2D FFT would take something like `O(n*m*(log n+log m))`.

To sum up: when you have a simple, localized filter, the best way to perform convolution is computing the sum directly. When you need to compute convolutions or correlations with bigger data (think correlation with another image) or perform complex operations, FFT can help you.